# Entity Framework, SaveChanges() doesnt work for specific entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

Here is my code:

```
static AogStatus status;

private void loadData()//Called if Page.IsPostback=false
{
        status = (from sta in dbContext.AogStatus
                 where sta.AOGStatus_Id == i_status_id
                 select sta).Single();
}

protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     status.Aircraft_Id = Int32.Parse(acReg.SelectedValue);
     status.Airport_Id = Int32.Parse(Station.SelectedValue);
     status.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;

     dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I click the Update button, it doesn't save the changes. It does not throw an exception. I'm using EF 4.3.1.. I couldn't figure out what is the problem.. Any ideas?? Thanks...

Comment: Well I forgot to mention why I've written "specific entity": there are other entities linked with this table and they update correctly when I call the same SaveChanges method.

Comment: @AdrianIftode I am in the learning stage, I got the idea it is a bad usage of static from your comment. I want the "status" to be assigned when page is loaded for the first time and I want to use same object when the user clicks update. But the problem is when user clicks button, status becomes null so I thought "static" can be a solution.

Comment: I'm afraid is a bad choice (think that two users can edit the same page, sharing the same object). However, you can "move" all this code in a separate class and handle there things like Save, Load.. Unfortunately I can't give you an answer here, hope someone will do. Is dbContext also static?

Comment: @AdrianIftode no, just "status". Also an update: I copied the linq query to the button click event and it worked. But now it runs an extra query to retrieve status object. I think EF cant get along well with global variables..

Comment: there is no problem to do an extra query. Are you encountering performance issues?

Comment: You can store the static variable in the `Session` if that's the problem.